# python color not filling in properly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've made a code that draws something like hair, and even though the two ends of the shape meets up, the color wouldn't fill in properly. 
[this is what I tried to imitate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bALkB.png) and
 [this is what I got, which is pretty ambarassing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGGEk.png)
I wasn't sure how to draw the arc I wanted, so I just filled them up with half circles. This is my code:

```
from turtle import*

myvarhead=200
def hair():
    rad1=(int(myvarhead)/7*4)
    color('black')
    begin_fill()

    #left side
    left(90)
    circle(rad1,180)
    right(120)
    forward(rad1/10)
    left(150)
    forward((rad1/10)*7)
    left(30)
    circle(rad1/4,160)
    circle(-rad1/4,120)
    right(10)
    forward((rad1/10)*3)
    #going back
    right(180)
    forward(rad1/10*3)
    left(10)
    circle(rad1/4,120)
    circle(-rad1/4,160)
    right(30)
    forward(rad1/10*7)
    right(150)
    forward(rad1/10)
    left(120)
    circle(-rad1,180)
    #right side
    left(120)
    forward(rad1/10)
    right(150)
    forward(rad1/10*7)
    right(30)
    circle(-rad1/4,160)
    circle(rad1/4,120)
    left(10)
    forward(rad1/10*3)
    right(180)
    end_fill()

hair()
right(90)
#forward(100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to not backtrack over your polygon but simply keep moving forward until you finish/close it:

```
from turtle import *

def hair():
    radius = (int(my_var_head) / 7 * 4)
    color('black')

    begin_fill()

    # top & left side
    left(90)
    circle(radius, 180)
    right(120)
    forward(radius / 10)
    left(150)
    forward((radius / 10) * 7)
    left(30)
    circle(radius / 4, 160)
    circle(-radius / 4, 120)
    right(10)
    forward((radius / 10) * 3)

    # right side

    forward((radius / 10) * 3)
    right(10)
    circle(-radius / 4, 120)
    circle(radius / 4, 160)
    left(30)
    forward((radius / 10) * 7)
    left(150)
    forward(radius / 10)

    end_fill()

my_var_head = 200
hair()
hideturtle()
done()
```

[image]